# Fragments without onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment-oncreateview

recently i saw some articles about inflating the fragment layout directly from the Fragment()

```
class ExampleFragment: Fragment(R.layout.example_fragment)
```

does this stand only for fragments that dont hold any data and interaction, when should we use this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added in [androidx.fragment version 1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment?hl=en#1.1.0):

> Fragment LayoutId constructor: Subclasses of Fragment can now optionally call into a constructor on Fragment that takes an R.layout ID, indicating the layout that should be used for this fragment as an alternative to overriding onCreateView(). The inflated layout can be configured in onViewCreated().

So in essence it's a shorthand for overriding `onCreateView()` that just inflates a layout and returns it, and encourages a style of configuring the view in `onViewCreated()` rather than `onCreateView()`.

Comment: If there's a configuration change, then the fragment manager is going to instantiate a new copy of your class through your sole empty constructor, which will pass the same layout ID to the superconstructor. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You're right, thanks. Will update the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to instantiate databinding in onviewcreated

Comment: override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding= FragmentFirstBinding.bind(view)}